# Search and View Details using ajax and php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, function

i am stuck in code and need your quick response to finish my project. I am able to pull all the data from database but when i click on view button, the details don't pop up in modal form. The button does not work. When i remove the click function button from while loop, it starts working. But i want view button in every row so i could display the details using modal.   Could someone please help to fix this?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 load_data();
 function load_data(query)
 {
  $.ajax({
   url:"fetch.php",
   method:"POST",
   data:{query:query},
   success:function(data)
   {
    $('#result').html(data);
   }
  });
 }
 $('#search_text').keyup(function(){
  var search = $(this).val();
  if(search != '')
  {
   load_data(search);
  }
  else
  {
   load_data();
  }
 });
 });

$('.view_data').click(function(){  
           var employee_id = $(this).attr("id");  
           $.ajax({  
                url:"select.php",  
                method:"post",  
                data:{employee_id:employee_id},  
                success:function(data){  
                     $('#employee_detail').html(data);  
                     $('#dataModal').modal("show");  
                }  
           });  
      });
```

PHP:

```
<?php
    //fetch.php
    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "crud");
    $output = '';
    if(isset($_POST["query"]))
    {
     $search = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["query"]);
     $query = "
      SELECT * FROM records
      WHERE User_ID LIKE '%".$search."%'
      OR User_Name LIKE '%".$search."%' 
      OR User_Email '%".$search."%' 
      OR User_Age LIKE '%".$search."%' 
      
     ";
    }
    else
    {
     $query = "
      SELECT * FROM records ORDER BY User_ID
     ";
    }
    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
    {
     $output .= '
      <div class="table-responsive">
       <table class="table table bordered">
        <tr>
         <th>User ID</th>
         <th>User Name</th>
         <th>User Email</th>
         <th>User Age</th>
         <th>View</th>
        </tr>
     ';
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
     {
      $output .= '
       <tr>
        <td>'.$row["User_ID"].'</td>
        <td>'.$row["User_Name"].'</td>
        <td>'.$row["User_Email"].'</td>
        <td>'.$row["User_Age"].'</td>
        <td><input type="button" name="view" value="view" id="'.$row["User_ID"].'" class="btn btn-info btn-xs view_data" /></td>
       </tr>
      ';
     }
     echo $output;
    }
    else
    {
     echo 'Data Not Found';
    }
    
    ?>

<?php  
     if(isset($_POST["employee_id"]))  
     {  
          $output = '';  
          $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "crud");  
          $query = "SELECT * FROM records WHERE User_ID = '".$_POST["employee_id"]."'";  
          $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);  
          $output .= '  
          <div class="table-responsive">  
               <table class="table table-bordered">';  
          while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
          {  
               $output .= '  
                    <tr>  
                         <td width="30%"><label>Name</label></td>  
                         <td width="70%">'.$row["User_ID"].'</td>  
                    </tr>  
                    <tr>  
                         <td width="30%"><label>Address</label></td>  
                         <td width="70%">'.$row["User_Name"].'</td>  
                    </tr>  
                    <tr>  
                         <td width="30%"><label>Gender</label></td>  
                         <td width="70%">'.$row["User_Email"].'</td>  
                    </tr>  
                    <tr>  
                         <td width="30%"><label>Designation</label></td>  
                         <td width="70%">'.$row["User_Age"].'</td>  
                    </tr>  
                     
                    ';  
          }  
          $output .= "</table></div>";  
          echo $output;  
     }  
     ?>
```

Comment: This probably won't solve your problem, but I don't think it's a good idea to use the HTML `id` attribute to store the `User_ID`. The `id` attribute has a special meaning for browsers, it uniquely identifies a HTML tag in the DOM, whereas you use it to transfer data to Javascript. There's a rule in programming I adhere to: "Only use things for what they are intended for.". It would be better to use `data-*` attributes. JQuery can cope with these. See: https://api.jquery.com/data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try changing this line:

```
$('body').on('click', '.view_data', function(){
/* old:
$('.view_data').click(function(){ */
```

Did it work?

The idea is that, in your version, the code will not work for two reasons:

- when you update the DOM with new `.view_data` elements, only the initial elements have this function attached (you have to recall the function for the new elements...)
- your function is run immediately then the document is loaded, when there are no `.view_data` elements in the DOM - so it has no effect when they appear asynchronously

The alternative suggested binds the click event to the `body`, then filters it by `.view_data`. Thus, no matter what changes in the DOM, the event is always triggered and the function works.

Comment: thank you it worked. is there any other method other than adding event in the body?

Comment: Cool. You can 1) add the event to any parent element that exists in the DOM when you define the function; 2) add the event individually for every new element added in the DOM, just make sure you don't duplicate them. Maybe there are other ways? But I use the first: put all dynamic elements in a predefined container (a div), which has all events binded to it.